# Do I use a comma?

Tags: commas

Is the comma appropriate in the following sentence:

You should change the title to "Water", or something similar.

Comment: It doesn't matter. This is a style issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your use of the comma is perfectly fine.  In this case, it serves to provide a pause before the next part of the statement.

Comment: From where I sit, you could have a comma there or not, and it wouldn't really matter either way. Also, you can't just answer "yes" and be done with it. You need to provide support for your contention. If you don't want to do that, write a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Commas in written text often coincide with pauses when the text is recited, but pauses in recitation are a poor guide to comma usage.  Check your manual of style.  Most will recommend that you not use a comma between compound objects.  Thus, "You could change the title to "Water" or "Hydration."  But they will recommend that a comma set off an aside, which might describe "or something similar."